# Where did unstable.rosdistro go?

Tags: ros, ros-release, rosdeb, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm finally getting around to releasing some of my stacks as debs. However, I thought you were supposed to start by editing the unstable distro, but now that seems to be gone.

Where did it go, and/or where do you start otherwise?

(I'm aware of these [Tutorials](http://ros.org/wiki/release/Setup) but I don't want to break the build by editing the electric distro incorrectly. )

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43819/where-did-unstable.rosdistro-go?/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2012-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

unstable was originally a distro which was designed to be a rolling release distro where integration happened and periodically it would be forked as things solidified towards a release.  However in reality this just ended up making a lot of work when things had to be renamed and documentation updated as releases approached.

Now we simply branch each rosdistro file from the previous one.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-09-13**:
So is the first step to building  a deb checking the changes into say electric.rosdistro? Or is there some other testing that happens first?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-09-13**:
I think I've got it.